# Is it possible to do this arithmetic directly in the MYSQL query rather than in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like so:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `profit_by_campaign` WHERE campaign_name = 'myCoolCampaign' AND request_date = '2017-10-16'";

try {
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    die('Error: unable to query ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

After fetching the results I do some logic like so:

```
$total_revenue = 0;
$total_spending = 0;

foreach($rows as $row) {
    $total_revenue += $row['revenue'];
    $total_spending += $row['spending'];
}

$total_profit = ($total_revenue - $total_spending);

echo $total_profit;
```

So basically I'm trying to get the total profits of a campaign by subtracting it's spending from it's revenue. My question is, is it possible to do this logic directly in the MYSQL query itself rather than in PHP?

Comment: Yes, using [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) like [SUM()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Sum(revenue+spending) as total_profit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT SUM(revenue - spending) AS profit
FROM profit_by_campaign
WHERE
    campaign_name = 'myCoolCampaign' AND
    request_date = '2017-10-16';
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard `$total_profit = ($total_revenue - $total_spending);`

Comment: It is summing everything, but then taking the diff at the very end.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Not enough coffee. +1

Comment: ...or in my case, way too many trips to the office Nespresso machine.

Comment: LOL, yup!  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯